# C# System.OverflowException Error in loops

Tags: c#

I'm trying to simplify someone's coding to let the codes be more readable. 
When I run the following code, however, I encountered "System.OverFlowException" error. I run the code in visual studio IDE. The function, "Transmit_Data" is used only to store an array of data. "TotalIndexToMod" is the array's length, "CurrentLoopIndexCnt" is the current looping index number of  "TotalIndexToMod". 
Below are the codes (in C#) :

```
int TotalIndexToMod = 28;
int MaxLoopIndexCnt = 16;


for (int mod = 0; mod < TotalIndexToMod; mod++)
{

    int LeftToMod = MaxLoopIndexCnt - CurrentLoopIndexCnt;

    Transmit_Data(mod, LeftToMod);

    CurrentLoopIndexCnt++;

    Console.WriteLine("CurrentIndexToMod / Mod/ Index : " + Convert.ToInt16(mod));
    CurrentIndexToMod = mod;
    Console.WriteLine("CurrentLoopIndexCnt : " + Convert.ToInt16(CurrentLoopIndexCnt));
    Console.WriteLine("MaxLoop : " + Convert.ToInt16(MaxLoop));
    Console.WriteLine("MaxLoopIndexCnt : " + Convert.ToInt16(MaxLoopIndexCnt));


    if (CurrentLoopIndexCnt > MaxLoopIndexCnt)
    {
        CurrentLoopCnt++;

        if (CurrentLoopCnt > MaxLoop) // last loop end
        {
            // byte Mod_State = (byte)(RxMsg.DATA[0] & 0x03);

            if (CurrentIndexToMod == 128)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (CurrentLoopCnt < MaxLoop)
            {
                MaxLoopIndexCnt = 16;
            }
            else if (CurrentLoopCnt == MaxLoop) // last loop
            {
                MaxLoopIndexCnt = SpareMaxLoopIndexCnt;
            }

            CurrentLoopIndexCnt = 1;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Not your issue, however i'd just like to point out "*code*" is singular in programming, *"This is my code"*. Additionally, this is not a reproducible example

Comment: So what's the point of the `Convert.ToInt16` calls (which would more commonly be written as `(short)` casts, or `checked { (short) .. }` casts if you wanted overflow checking)? These are likely the cause of your exceptions, meaning there are integers exceeding `Int16.MaxValue`, but the rest of your code doesn't make it clear if that should be a problem (and if so, what the fix should be).

Comment: If you have debugged it, you may point out which line is getting the exception. Provide the argument value in post as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably error occurs in method [Convert.ToInt16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint16?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt16_System_Int32_).
So please make sure that values are not outside the range of the [Int16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int16?view=netframework-4.8) type.

Please also consider overloaded method [WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_) with format string parameter.
In this way the following line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine("CurrentIndexToMod / Mod/ Index : " + Convert.ToInt16(mod));
```

will be look like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("CurrentIndexToMod / Mod/ Index : {0}", mod);
```